# Put MXF video into a MOV container with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to put MXF video and audio tracks into a single MOV container with FFMPEG. I would like to maintain the existing video format. My FFMPEG build parameters are the following:

```
ffmpeg version N-52045-g694fa00
built on Apr 12 2013 17:00:02 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enabl
e-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-lib
opus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --en
able-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 26.100 / 52. 26.100
libavcodec     55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavformat    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
libavfilter     3. 53.101 /  3. 53.101
libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
```

I first tried to do a audio and video pass through:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Sample\video.mxf" -i "C:\Sample\audioOne.mxf" -i "C:\Sample\audioTwo.mxf" -map 0 -c:v copy -map 1 -map 2 -c:a copy sampleOut.mov
```

That results in an error stating: **Data Streaming Encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)**.

Could not get that to work so I tried to simplify it a little and just do a video only conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Sample\video.xml" -c:v copy test.mov
```

But that results in an error stating: ****Output file #0 does not contain any stream.**

Also tried option (-vcodec copy with same error). According to MediaInfo my MXF is a valid stream..

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : VC-3
Format_Settings_Wrapping                 : Clip
Codec ID                                 : 4B464141000D4D4F-0E04020102040100
Duration                                 : 35s 2ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 145 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.339
Stream size                              : 606 MiB (100%)
```

Do I need a special build or am I missing some command to change the container?

EDIT:

Here is FFMPEG response for my first command with trying to splice audio and video:

```
Input #0, mxf, from 'C:\MXF\Sample\video.mxf':
  Metadata:
    product_name    : Avid Media Toolkit
    uid             : 746488ad-3ee0-447b-9473-bc467dedde5c
    generation_uid  : 9f1a9ae1-0cbf-822f-cea4-f34822c44135
    application_platform: Win32
    modification_date:
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-000a-060e-2b347f7f2a80
    product_version : 2.2.1.53
    company_name    : Avid
  Duration: 00:00:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 145505 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Data: none
Input #1, mxf, from 'C:\MXF\Sample\audio1.mxf':
  Metadata:
    product_name    : Avid Media Toolkit
    uid             : 5489b584-3529-4e1a-92ee-77fad0dd9909
    generation_uid  : a74c9e25-f381-1ca1-8415-28324a9b45d9
    application_platform: Win32
    modification_date:
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-000a-060e-2b347f7f2a80
    product_version : 2.2.1.53
    company_name    : Avid
  Duration: 00:00:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 928 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Data: none
Input #2, mxf, from 'C:\MXF\Sample\audio2.mxf':
  Metadata:
    product_name    : Avid Media Toolkit
    uid             : dafe5f12-7e31-448d-b5eb-ab1d31f5ec65
    generation_uid  : 9bd46aa8-7107-3b41-3d16-2824563a43aa
    application_platform: Win32
    modification_date:
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-000a-060e-2b347f7f2a80
    product_version : 2.2.1.53
    company_name    : Avid
  Duration: 00:00:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 928 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Data: none
Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)
```

Here is the second with just trying to do a simple video conversion:

```
nput #0, mxf, from 'C:\MXF\Sample\video.mxf':
  Metadata:
    product_name    : Avid Media Toolkit
    uid             : 746488ad-3ee0-447b-9473-bc467dedde5c
    generation_uid  : 9f1a9ae1-0cbf-822f-cea4-f34822c44135
    application_platform: Win32
    modification_date:
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-000a-060e-2b347f7f2a80
    product_version : 2.2.1.53
    company_name    : Avid
  Duration: 00:00:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 145505 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Data: none
Output #0, mov, to 'test.mov':
  Metadata:
    product_name    : Avid Media Toolkit
    uid             : 746488ad-3ee0-447b-9473-bc467dedde5c
    generation_uid  : 9f1a9ae1-0cbf-822f-cea4-f34822c44135
    application_platform: Win32
    modification_date:
    product_uid     : 00000000-0000-000a-060e-2b347f7f2a80
    product_version : 2.2.1.53
    company_name    : Avid
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I have also tried variants of "-dcodec copy" and "-c:d" copy but it continually gives me that error. I wonder if it is because the codec (DnxHD) underneath cannot be translated to MOV?

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output from each command. You can trim out lines that repeat many times.